# How to pick specific files in directory, python

Tags: python

Please help, i would like to pick only 3 specific documents out of `folder` directory (`template1.docx`, `template2.docx`, `template3.docx`), but it gives me all that is featured in the mentioned directory.

How can I modify the code to pick only mentioned files?

```
folder = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\pyinst")
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder)]
```

Comment: `filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder) if fname in ['template1.docx', 'template2.docx', 'template3.docx']]` You can also use regex if you need a more complex pattern.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Also, consider the `glob` module.  It will be easier than filtering results yourself [PMOTW glob](https://pymotw.com/3/glob/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using if at the end of loop.

```py
folder = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\pyinst")
filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder) if fname =='template1.docx' or fname=='template2.docx']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
folder = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\pyinst")
filelist1 = [fname for fname in os.listdir(folder)]
dr =  "C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\pyinst\\"
name_list = ['template1.docx', 'template2.docx', 'template3.docx']
filelist2 = [dr+file for file in name_list]
filelist_final = list(set(filelist1) & set(filelist2))
```

Comment: first of you shouldn't use `dir` as a variable name, second what if the file with that names is not in that folder? then you will have a list with non-existant paths, also you should add a bit more explanation to your answer

Comment: hope this helps now

Comment: that is not an explanation but at least you solved two of the "issues" I mentioned

Comment: I dont understand "you should" part of your comment!!! I am new here and thought this platform would be about sharing and helping and everyone should be polite

Comment: ironically you yourself used "should" in your sentence so you should know what that means but basically in this case it would mean almost the same as "I suggest" (not exactly but I hope you get the point), also again ironically you talk about helping everyone while not adding any helpful explanation to your code, the point is that some people may not understand what your code does, so you should explain it, and btw I in no way meant to be rude if that is what you meant by: "everyone should be polite"

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `os.path.join` method over `os.chdir` as it doesn't change your working directory (unless you have a need for that).

```py
folder = "C:\\Users\\****\\Desktop\\pyinst"
file_names = ["template1.docx", "template2.docx", "template3.docx"]
file_list = [os.path.join(folder, file_name) for file_name in file_names]
```